# RTL getBy method followed by toBeInDocument

Tags: reactjs, react-testing-library

I see a common pattern in RTL to check if the element is in the body directly after a get query.

```
test('render Hello World', () => {
  render(<App />);

  const hello = screen.getByText('Hello World');

  expect(hello).toBeInTheDocument();
});
```

Isn't it redundant?

From documentation it states get queries will throw error if not found.

Will there be ever any case where get succeeds but element is not in document?

Comment: While it may be redundant, it does make the assertion explicit.

Answer (score 0):

> Isn't it redundant?

Personally I agree with you, I find it redundant too.

> Will there be ever any case where get succeeds but element is not in document?

Nope !

The creator of `react-testing-library` has written a few line about it saying it is more a matter of tastes, no big deal
https://kentcdodds.com/blog/common-mistakes-with-react-testing-library#using-get-variants-as-assertions